# Failed to start RabbitMq redentials_obfuscation

Tags: rabbitmq

Any one came across this problem?

Rabbitmq:3.8.14

when run:

$ sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server

got this **credentials obfuscation** problem:

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,cr
A nel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,credentials_obfuscation,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,credentials_obfu
l redentials_obfuscation,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,credentials_obfuscaton_svc,{undef,[{crypto,cipher_info,[aes_128_cbc],[]},{credentials_ob
ede uscaton_svc,{undef,[{crypto,cipher_info,[aes_128_cbc],[]},{credentials_obfuscation_pbe,iv_length,1,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_pbe.erl"
sca bfuscation_pbe,iv_length,1,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_pbe.erl"},{line,125}]},{credentials_obfuscation_pbe,encrypt,5,[{file,"src/crede
"},{line,125}]},{credentials_obfuscation_pbe,encrypt,5,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_pbe.erl"},{line,75}]},{credentials_obfuscation_svc,c
entials_obfuscation_pbe.erl"},{line,75}]},{credentials_obfuscation_svc,check,3,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_svc.erl"},{line,163}]},{cre
check,3,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_svc.erl"},{line,163}]},{credentials_obfuscation_svc,init_state,0,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscati
edentials_obfuscation_svc,init_state,0,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_svc.erl"},{line,133}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}},{credentials_obfuscation_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Answer (score 1):

After few hours spending on this,  it turns out to be the Erlang was too old. Upgraded it to latest version Erlang/OTP 23, problem solved!

the problem cause by incompatible between RabbitMQ and Erlang/OTP:
Ubuntu 18.04 provides Erlang 20.2 and [RabbitMQ 3.8.14 requires 22.3 or 23.x](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.14). See [RabbitMQ and Erlang/OTP Compatibility Matrix](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html#compatibility-matrix)

Installing latest Erlang version should solve the problem.

```
$sudo apt-get install erlang
```

The problem commonly happens when only upgrade rabbitMq without Erlang. (as my case: rabbitMq 3.8.0 -> 3.8.14)